# I have directory (folder) where the attributes revert back to read-only after I change it. win7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7

it's the funkiest thing.  Windows 7 workstation. Peer to peer network. As administrator, I change the file attributes from read only, only to look at it an hour and it has changed back. When I go into properties and look at security, an unidentified user is there and then vanishes.  I use Trend Micro Titanium and it hasn't detected any trojan horses.
I have data that users are constantly changing in that folder and it is time consuming to repeatedly change attributes just to have them change back.

Answer (score 0):

Set [auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738931%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on an object, then see who makes the changes in the "Security" [event log](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427).